# Using a Function within a Sub Procedure VBA

Tags: vba, excel, function

I don't think I'm searching the right terms as I imagine this answer has to be somewhere but I am new to functions and trying to figure out how to get this to work:

How can I get my function `findLastRow` to be used where I say `Range("B2" & findLastRow).Select` ?  The current error I recieve is **Argument Not Optional** and it highlights `findLastRow`

```
Public Function findLastRow(col As String) As Long 'making the macro available to all Sub Procedures

        Dim lastRow As Long
        With ActiveSheet
            lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(1048576, col).End(xlUp).Row 'finding the last possible row disregarding blanks
        End With

        findLastRow = lastRow
End Function

Sub Open_INV()

    ChDir "C:\Users\MonthEnd_Close\Import_Files"
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\MonthEnd_Close\Import_Files\INV", _
        Origin:=437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
        xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False _
        , Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    On Error Resume Next

    Range("B2").Formula = "=TRIM(A2)"
    Range("B2").Copy
    Range("B2:B" & findLastRow).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
End Sub
```

Comment: maybe `Range("B2:B" & findLastRow).Select` ?

Comment: Fixed that part, thank you!  However I still receive the error "Argument Not Optional"

Comment: In calling the formula in your `Sub`, you are omitting the `col` argument.  `Range("B2:B" & findLastRow("B"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use ActiveSheet in a function. You have a perfect opportunity to pass in a range that has a defined parent worksheet rather than a string representing the column letter.

```
Public Function findLastRow(col As range) As Long 'making the macro available to all Sub Procedures

        Dim lastRow As Long
        With col.parent
            lastRow = .Cells(.rows.count, col.column).End(xlUp).Row 'finding the last possible row disregarding blanks
        End With

        findLastRow = lastRow

End Function

Sub Open_INV()
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\MonthEnd_Close\Import_Files\INV", _
        Origin:=437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
        xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False _
        , Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    with activeworkbook.worksheets(1)
        .Range("B2:B" & findLastRow(.range("A2"))).Formula = "=TRIM(A2)"
    end with
End Sub
```

Comment: I received an "Invalid Qualifier" error for findLastRow

Comment: Looks like I missed a closing bracket ad you should probably be looking for the last row in column A, not column B. Use the last row from column A to extend the range in column B.

Comment: @Jeeped: Would `col.End(xlUp).Row` be just as valid?

Comment: @AJD Only if called as `findLastRow(.cells(.rows.count, "A"))`